# Alternate of quoteInto in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using this query in api

```
if (isset($json['version'])) {
        $client_cache_version =  @$json['version'];

        $version_sql = $db->quoteInto("SELECT max(messageVersion) as version FROM messageTable");
        $version_results = $db->fetchAll($version_sql);

        $version_array = $version_results['0'];

        $max_version = $version_array['version'];

        if($max_version > $client_cache_version){

            $sql = $db->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM messageTable");
            $results = $db->fetchAll($sql);

            $count = array(
                'count' => sizeof($results)
            );
```

all code working fine but problem in

```
$version_sql = $db->quoteInto("SELECT max(messageVersion) as version FROM messageTable");
```

when i try to check this code on curl I got this error

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::quoteInto()
```

I know in the case of `Using quoteInto()` multiple arguments are reguired but i have not an multiple argument right now so what i can do ?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote-into. I don't understand why are you using this function.

Comment: @legiero :) I have this link I already studied ok so any alternate option this is not working for single argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Zend API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/) on `Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::quoteInto()`:

The placeholder is a question-mark; all placeholders will be replaced with the quoted value. For example:

```
$text = "WHERE date < ?";
$date = "2005-01-02";
$safe = $sql->quoteInto($text, $date);
// $safe = "WHERE date < '2005-01-02'"
```

--

```
Parameters
Name   Type     Description
$text  string   The text with a placeholder.
$value mixed    The value to quote. 
$type  string   OPTIONAL SQL datatype
$count integer OPTIONAL count of placeholders to replace

Returns
Type    Description
string  An SQL-safe quoted value placed into the original text.
```

Note that the value is REQUIRED. You shouldn't be using this method if you're not binding any params.

Comment: :) yes I know that thanks but i want to know what i can do in my case :) cheers

Comment: Really? Skip your method entirely and just pass the query into `fetchAll()`. Do you understand what your code does?